# Ektron Solr Search Installation - Error: This server does not have the windows authentication role service enabled.

Tags: windows-server

I get this when trying to run the Ektron SOLR installation:

> This server does not have the windows authentication role service
>   enabled. Please enable it from the Windows Server Mnaager before
>   continuiing the Solr installation. The install will now close

Answer (score 1):

This requirement is listed in http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v9.10/Reference/Web/EktronReferenceWeb.html#Search/solr.htm  > Setting up Solr Search > Setting up Solr Search on a Single On-Premises (Local) Server > Prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

You can't install it to a machine without the Windows Authentication Role installed.

Windows 8 Standard doesn't support this feature, you need at least Windows 8 **Pro**.